# Concatenate Trigger?

Tags: trigger, formula

I have this apex class, how can I achive to display unique values under the Description field on the account?

public class updateaccountrating
{

```
public void updaterating(List<Opportunity> oppor)
{
    List<ID> parentIDstoUpdate = new List<ID>();
    Map<Id,Account> accountMap = new Map<Id,Account>();
    map<id,string>  mapParentIdtoString = new Map<ID,String>();
    string str;

        for (Opportunity co : oppor) {
            parentIDstoUpdate.add(co.accountid); 
             system.debug('parentIDstoUpdate' + parentIDstoUpdate);
        }



    for (Opportunity co: [SELECT StageName, accountid FROM Opportunity WHERE accountid in : parentIDstoUpdate order by StageName asc ]){

        system.debug('oppco' + co);

        if(mapParentIdtoString.containsKey(co.accountid)){
            str = mapParentIdtoString.get(co.accountid);
            str = str + '; ' + co.StageName;  
            mapParentIdtoString.put(co.accountid,str);
        }else{
            mapParentIdtoString.put(co.accountid,co.StageName);
        }
    }
    list<Account> recordstoUpdate = new list<Account>();
    for (Account p: [SELECT ID, Description FROM Account WHERE id in :mapParentIdtoString.keyset()]){ 
        p.Description = mapParentIdtoString.get(p.id);
        recordstoUpdate.add(p);
    }

    if (recordstoUpdate != null && recordstoUpdate.size() >0){
        update recordstoUpdate;
    }



}
```

}

Comment: You can accomplish this requirement quite easily with dlrs. Operation would be Concatenate distinct, with a comma delimiter and order by. Can't really flesh out into a full answer while travelling but that's the idea.

Comment: This is very very weird requirement, what is the Use-Case?

Comment: I have this parent Account, then I have a child which is the opportunity, what I want to achieve is that the stagename will be put into a field in account wherein in my testing I put it first on Site field, I want to concatenate all the stagename in every record to one filed in account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have implemented everything other than the distinctness part of this requirement. You can achieve this by, instead of concatenating the stage names as you iterate over Opportunities, accumulating a `Set<String>`, and only when you perform the Account update generating a concatenated `String`.

You would change

```
map<id,string>  mapParentIdtoString = new Map<ID,String>();
```

to

```
Map<Id, Set<String>> mapParentIdtoString = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();
```

and

```
    if(mapParentIdtoString.containsKey(co.accountid)){
        str = mapParentIdtoString.get(co.accountid);
        str = str + '; ' + co.StageName;  
        mapParentIdtoString.put(co.accountid,str);
    }else{
        mapParentIdtoString.put(co.accountid,co.StageName);
    }
```

to

```
    if (!mapParentIdtoString.containsKey(co.AccountId)){
        mapParentIdtoString.put(co.AccountId, new Set<String>());
    }

    mapParentIdtoString.get(co.AccountId).add(co.StageName);
```

Then, your Account updates can be a little more efficient, because you don't need to re-query those objects to perform the update:

```
list<Account> recordstoUpdate = new list<Account>();
for (Id p : mapParentIdtoString.keySet()){ 
    String desc = String.join(new List<String>(mapParentIdtoString.get(p)), '; ');
    recordstoUpdate.add(new Account(Id = p, Description = desc));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much David for helping me! it was a tough one for me :)

Comment: My pleasure! The `Set` is a great capability to remember any time you have a need for uniqueness. By the way, you can just do `update recordstoUpdate` - you don't need that `if` at the end.